# I need to make all branch same

Tags: git, version-control

i have three branch Production , Staging and integration.
Production is parent of staging and staging is parent of integration.

my issue is mistakenly i had add commit in production and staging separately from my local so from now all three branch is different now.

I just need to make staging and integration branch make same as production. it means i just need to make staging and integration copy from production . so need to put all production code in staging and integration so i can commit all together. 
Please share your idea

Comment: remove staging and integration and create them again, from production.

Comment: You could merge all of them with production.

Comment: i can't delete any branch becauseits already assign with dns

Comment: i getting error while merge this because all commit and code are different now

Comment: any idea guys ?

Comment: staging branch is already connected with staging domain

Comment: for that i just go back to support from server side and it will taking a time brother. this branch is created by cloud server

Comment: is there any other way to make them same except deleting branch ?

Comment: locally means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of below options to make `staging` branch and `integration` branch same  as `production` branch.

#### Option 1: reset `staging` and `integration` branches, then force push to remote

You can use below commands to achieve:

```
git checkout production
git checkout -B staging
git push -u origin staging -f
git checkout -B integration
git push -u origin integration -f
```

**Note:** `-B` option for checkout branchname will reset the branchname to current `HEAD` if the branchname already existing in your local repo. Such as executing `git checkout -B staging` from `production` branch, will reset local `staging` branch from `production` branch.

#### Option 2: merge `production` branch into `staging` and `integration` branches separately with `theirs` strategy

You can use below commands:

```
git checkout staging 
git merge production -X theirs
git checkout integration
git merge production -X theirs
```

**Note:** `-X theirs` option for `git merge` will resolve the merge conflict files automatically by using the version from `production` branch.

Comment: in first solution what is use of git checkout production. i already available in there directory in my local. so its need to use this line ?

Comment: `git checkout -B branchname` will reset the existing `branchname` point to the same commit as `production` branch (your situation). If the `branchname` doesn't exist, the command will work as same `git checkout -b branchname`.  You can also find more details about `-B` option for `git checkout` here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout.

Comment: Thank You . Let me try .

Comment: Its Working. Thanks

Comment: i need to know one more thing from you . Now if i change any file in my local . then use git push origin production. right. but how can i also same thing push on staging and integration branch. i have use single project for all this three branch

Comment: You can merge `production` branch into `staging` and `integration` branch separately. Or you can use `git checkout -B staging` and `git checkout -B integration` commands again from `production branch`. Then the `staging` branch and `integration` branch will be updated.